# How to use json_serializable package for complex response models - Flutter

Tags: flutter, json-serializable

I have seen several examples on how to use `json_serializable` package to auto-generate response models. But almost all of these examples have simple response structure.
For example, have a look at the Json response for a student's data.

```
{
  "name": "Something",
  "age": 12,
  "id": 2773
}
```

It's fairly easy to serialize this Json response. One of the ways is below

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Student {
  String name;
  int age;
  int roll_number;
 
  Student(
    this.name,
    this.age,
    this.roll_number,
  ) {}

  factory Student.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> input) => _$StudentFromJson(input);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$StudentToJson(this);
}
```

I am considering this example as simple because the response does not contain any non-primitive data in it.
Let's take a look at this response now

```
{
  "name": "Something",
  "age": 12,
  "id": 2773,
  "marks": {
    "physics": 30,
    "maths": 20,
    "english": 30,
  }
}
```

We can have the files layed out like this

In the file `student.dart`

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Student {
  String name;
  int age;
  int roll_number;
  Marks marks;
 
  Student(
    this.name,
    this.age,
    this.roll_number,
    this.marks
  ) {}

  factory Student.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> input) => _$StudentFromJson(input);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$StudentToJson(this);
}
```

And in the file `marks.dart`

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Marks {
  int physics;
  int maths;
  int english;
 
  Marks(
    this.physics,
    this.maths,
    this.english,
  ) {}

  factory Marks.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> input) => _$MarksFromJson(input);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$MarksToJson(this);
}
```

I have two questions for the latter response scenario.

1. If the response contains non-primitive data, is it necessary to serialize those data in a separate file, as I did with the `Marks` class. Or is there a way by which I can keep the class `Marks` in the file `student.dart` and serialize the whole response. If I can, how?
2. My actual question was related to a project that i'm working on, in which I have multiple API calls in different sections of the project. The API response follows a same skeletal structure i.e.

```
Response {
 primitive data variables,
 Data data,
}
```

I'm receiving the actual response data in the `Data` class. Suppose I follow the serializing pattern that I mentioned in the example above, i.e. serialize `Response` class in one file and serialize `Data`  class in another.
Then i’ll have multiple `Data` class files all over the project. Won’t that create confusion to the other developers as to which `data.g.dart` file belongs to which `response.g.dart`  file. The class `Response`’s name would be different depending on what type of response it fetches, for instance, `DogResponse` or `UserResponse`. But the `key` that stores the actual data in each of these response classes will have the same name i.e. `Data`, at least it has the same name in current scenario.
Is there a way where I could keep the `Data` class of each response class in the response class itself? If now, how shall I tackle this problem of serialization.